# toggle checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, mustache

I am trying to toggle the value of a checkbox using the following code:

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label checkbox" for="IsViewAsWebpage">
            {{#if this.IsViewAsWebpage}}
                <input type="hidden" id="IsViewAsWebpage" name="IsViewAsWebpage" value="true"/> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" checked /> 
            {{else}}
                <input type="hidden" id="IsViewAsWebpage" name="IsViewAsWebpage" value="false"/> 
                <input type="checkbox" class="enable-checkbox" /> 
            {{/if}}
            <span>View as Webpage</span>
        </label>
    </div>



'click .enable-checkbox': function (e) {
                if (e.currentTarget.parentElement.htmlFor == "IsViewAsWebpage") {
                     this.$('#IsViewAsWebpage').is(':checked');
            }

        }
```

I know I am misssing something in the click function. I would basically want to toggle the checkbox value when the user clicks on it. Can someone point me to the right directions pls. Thank you.

Comment: What append to your Javascript Oo ?

Comment: uhm, this is the weirdest JS code that I have ever seen. Can you post the rendered markup?

Comment: These are separate files. Just posted the code together

Comment: Why are you setting the checked attribute to a hidden input field?

Comment: Note that IDs must be unique.

Comment: @undefined - Mustache will only include one of those blocks when it template renders the page.

Comment: @Aesthete: True. I am trying to get the right value posted when the form is submitted. Checking on Firebug - toggling doesnt change the checkbox values that are submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your checkbox gets clicked, it's going to toggle. That's the way checkboxes work.

If you want the hidden input to change `value` when the checkbox is toggled, I think what you want is this:

```
$(".enable-checkbox").change(function (e) {
    if($(this).parent().attr("for") == "IsViewAsWebpage") {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked"); // Returns true/false.
        $('#IsViewAsWebpage').attr("value", checked); // Sets true/false.
    }        
});
```

Comment: I tried the above. But the value being posted still doesn't toggle. Eg. IsViewAsWebpage is false when loaded, then I check it and hit Submit.... it still posts as false

Comment: No matter what I do, checked above is returning false

Comment: @Aesthete: I used e.currentTarget.parentElement.htmlFor in the if loop to capture the right checkbox value. That works, but the problem is the next statement which always returns false

Comment: @dotNetNewbie - Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/gWWVB/1/ - I'm logging the results to the console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16801/discussion-between-dotnetnewbie-and-aesthete)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use handlebars.js to switch content when you click an check box, you will need to replace your content by calling handlebars each time you make a modification to your checkbox

```
$(".enable-checkbox").change(function (e) {
    if($(this).parent().attr("for") == "IsViewAsWebpage") {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        IsViewAsWebpage = checked;
        $("#yourcontainer").html(Handlebars.compile(yourtemplatesource));
    }

}
```

then your IsViewAsWebpage variable should be global and your mustache condition should only be :

```
{{#if IsViewAsWebpage}}
```

But this is complicated for nothing... just use Aesthete solution, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Change will not fire unless the input loose focus. If you want it to take effect immediately you will need to add Click to the listener. But keep change, mouse is not the only way to check a checkbox